# <mx:HTML/> content Resize in Flex 4.6 AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, flex4.5

I am working in Flex 4.6 AIR application. I open a gif image in html component. The Code is below:

```
var cuteDog:HTML = new HTML();
                    cuteDog.location=url;               
                    cuteDog.height = 142;
                    cuteDog.width = 180;
                    cuteDog.horizontalScrollPolicy = "off";
                    cuteDog.verticalScrollPolicy = "off";               
                    this.addElement(cuteDog);
```

The url is the path of the animated gif image. I want to display the full image in this width and height without scroll of html component if image has any size.
The Image is displaying look like this:

[image]

But i want to image should be display look like this in the html component:

[image]

How can i achieve this. please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could code a HTML page that includes a <img> tag that displays the GIF, and then show that? Image tag will let you control the size of the image, so you can manipulate it to your liking.

Comment: Thanks jpop for your comment. I am trying this using another way but is has some problem like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825914/gifplayer-not-working-in-flex-4-6-air