# GIFPlayer Not working in Flex 4.6 AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5, animated-gif

I am working with Flex 4.6 AIR Application. I am using GIFPlayer for play animated gif file. I have a TileList and I use a itemRenderer for displaying this image. The problem is it hangs the AIR application when it loads. I am using the library of GIFPlayer you can download it from [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/as3gif/downloads/detail?name=GIFPlayer%200.6.zip)

The code of itemRenderer is below.

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    if(value != null)
    {
        super.data = value;
        var gif:GIFPlayer = new GIFPlayer();
        gif.load(new URLRequest(data.image));                       
        var uic:UIComponent = new UIComponent(); 
        uic.addChild(gif);
        this.addElement(uic);                       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `set data` should better look like:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;

    if(value != null)
    {
        gif.load(new URLRequest(data.image));                       
    }   
}
```

and the other methods called in the constructor or `createChildren` method

Comment: Ok, I will try and get back to you on this.